# Change the content of a file from filename

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I want to write a script in which content of file is change based on its filename.

Suppose I have a file named `ABC_20161027220153.txt` and content of file is like

```
2000|2000_ABC|04|||0000000000||
```

I want to make a script in which file content are change like below

```
2000|2000_ABC|04|20161027|27.10.2016 22.01.53|0000000000||
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your script can take the file name as a command line argument. You can then call this argument in the script with the $1 variable and manipulate that variable however you see fit.
E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript.sh

year=`echo $1 | cut -c 5-8`
month=`echo $1 | cut -c 9-10`
day=`echo $1 | cut -c 11-12`

# Etc...
# Then...

repstr=`echo "$year$month$day|$day.$month.$year $hour.$minute.$second"`

sed -i "s/|||/$repstr/" $1
```

Then call the script like this:

```
./myscript.sh ABC_20161027220153.txt
```

Comment: How can we call filename argument in the script with the $1 variable ? Will script will directly take $1 variable as my parameter ?

Comment: The answer I've provided shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

find . -name 'ABC_*.txt' | while read file; do
    res=$( echo "$file" | 
    sed -r 's#\S*_(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..).*#\1\2\3|\3.\2.\1 \4.\5.\6#' )

    col4=${res%|*}
    col5=${res#*|}

    sed -r -i.bak '
    s#(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|#\1|\2|\3|'"$col4"'|'"$col5"'|\6|\7|#' \
    "$file"
done
```